# d3.js - table partially visible when insert to group element

Tags: d3.js

I want to insert a ta

```js
console.clear()

var parsed = d3.csvParse(get_csv_text())
var g = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.append('g')

csv_table(g,parsed)
function csv_table(g,parsed) {
  var caption = "demo table"
 
 var xoff = 50
 var yoff = 50
  var width = 400
  var height = 800
 
  var headers = [Object.keys(parsed[0])]
  var table = g.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr('x',xoff)
  .attr('y',yoff)
  .append("xhtml:table")
  .style('font-weight','bold')
    
  var thead = table.append("thead")
  var tbody = table.append("tbody")
  var tfoot = table.append("tfoot")

  thead.selectAll("tr")
    .data(headers).enter()
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(d => d).enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(d => d)
   .style('border-bottom','1px solid black')
  
  tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(parsed).enter()
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("td")
    .data(d => {
    var elem = Object.entries(d).map(d => d[1])
        return elem
  }).enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(d => d)

  thead.selectAll('tr')
  .style('color','black')
  .style('text-align','left')
  
  g.selectAll('table')
    .style('border-top','2px solid black')
  .style('border-bottom','1.5px solid black')
    
  tbody.selectAll('tr')
  .style('text-align','left')
  
  tbody.selectAll('tr:nth-child(even)')           
      .style('background-color','#eee')

 table.append("caption")
    .text(caption)
}

function get_csv_text() {
  var data =`name,x,y
aaaaaaaaaaaa,8712.0,10631.0
b,9951.0,11806.0
c,12698.0,14797.0
d,13246.0,15391.0
e,14959.0,17237.0
f,15445.0,17842.0
g,26727.0,30004.0
h,8712.0,10631.0
i,9951.0,11806.0
j,12698.0,14797.0
k,13246.0,15391.0
l,14959.0,17237.0
m,15445.0,17842.0
n,26727.0,30004.0
`
  return data
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

How to make the element always fit the table?

Answer (score 0):

The svg element is too small. You can move the height and width attributes up, and then use `.attr("width", width).attr("height", height)` after the `.append('svg')`.